# Cloudinary Upload Image API with ReactJS and Node- Status Error Message 500

Tags: node.js, reactjs, error-handling, fetch, cloudinary

I am using ReactJS and Node to build a Cloudinary Image Upload/Gallery. Everything was working until I tested the app out to check if it uploaded the images to my Cloudinary account. Everything loads perfectly when I hit the upload button on the app and add a picture. The problem starts when I hit the submit button, the picture disappears, but in the console it throws an error saying 500 Internal Server Error (I included a few screenshots of the console and code to help understand the problem better).

[![This is a screenshot of the error message that I keep getting after I hit the submit button to upload a picture to Cloudinary][1]][1]

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsIJf.png




[![This is the code on the frontend React app. I am using fetch to get the API from 
Cloudinary. According to the error message in the console, the problem is in the 
handleSubmitFile and the uploadImage functions ][1]][1]

const handleSubmitFile = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!selectedFile) return;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
    reader.onloadend = () => {
        uploadImage(reader.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = () => {
        console.error('Error');
    };
};

const uploadImage = async (base64EncodedImage) => {
    try {
        await fetch('/api/upload', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ data: base64EncodedImage }),
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        });
        setFileInputState('');
        setPreviewSource('');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}; 



[![This code is from the backend using Node.][2]][2]

const { cloudinary } = require('./utils/cloudinary');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors');

app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

app.get('/api/images', async (req, res) => {
const { resources } = await cloudinary.search
    .expression('folder: South Korea_Image Gallery')
    .sort_by('public_id', 'desc')
    .max_results(30)
    .execute();

const publicIds = resources.map((file) => file.public_id);
res.send(publicIds);
});

app.post('/api/upload', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const fileStr = req.body.data;
    const uploadResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(fileStr, {
        upload_preset: 'react_cloudinary',
    });
    console.log(uploadResponse);
    res.json({ msg: 'File uploaded sucessfully' });
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ err: 'Something went wrong' });
}
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log('listening on 3001');
});

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQBNE.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXWvx.png
```

Comment: The 500 Internal Server Error is returned from the request to localhost:3000/api/upload. What do you see on the logs on the backend server?

Comment: I'm seeing "Must supply api_key". I don't understand why it's giving me this message on the logs because I have a .env file where I stored the api name/apikey/ and the apisecretkey the Cloudinary requires

Comment: It sounds like the SDK either does not have access to load the env file or the keys defined there may not be the one checked by the SDK. Could you confirm the keys you are using in your ENV (values should not be shared)?

Comment: I am not sure whether I need to include the CLOUDINARY_URL or not but I attempted uploading with and without it and I keep getting the same error 
CLOUDINARY_NAME= 
CLOUDINARY_API_KEY= 
CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET=

Comment: When I tried to change the api url in my uploadImage function it changed the error message to 400 (Bad Request). I'm not sure if I'm fetching the incorrect url. This is the code that gave me the 400 error msg in my console await fetch('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUD_NAME/upload'